# Unable to ping IP Address of CentOS 7 Server

Tags: centos7, linux-networking

I am facing a problem that I cannot figure out and I really really need your help.

1. I have a CentOS 7 server with 2 network interfaces:

   [image: IP_Information]
2. Network of interface eth2 (172.30.0.99) is down and **I cannot ping to it from outside**. I checked and saw that: interface is still up (I can saw IP address on command line), it still can ping to another IP on the same network, but it cannot ping to gateway.

   [image: Ping_Problem]

   I tried to restart network service as well as ifdown/ifup interface but not OK.

   Also I checked carefully and no IP conflict for my issue.
3. From another host on the same network with problem host, I still can ping to problem host as normal.
4. On problem host, /var/log/messages file has nothing related to problem.
5. I worked with my network team and cannot figure out the root cause. No problem with network for problem host.
6. My server is virtual machine and it is running under vmware esxi. I have to overcome my problem by deleting network card for interface eth2, add another network card on esxi, re-configure IP address and it will be normal. But this solution is only work for a few weeks, after that my issue is happen again.
   Here is my network configuration for interface eth2:

   ```
   #eth2 (updated by "/bin/fstool netconfig" on Thu Oct  1 11:49:30 2020)
   HWADDR="00:xx:xx:yy:xx:zz"
   IPV6INIT="no"
   DEVICE="eth2"
   NETMASK="255.255.255.248"
   NOZEROCONF="yes"
   BROADCAST="172.30.0.103"
   IPADDR="172.30.0.99"
   NETWORK="172.30.0.96"
   ONBOOT="yes"
   #NM_CONTROLLED=yes
   #Will have your network interface be managed the NetworkManager daemon
   #NM_CONTROLLED=no

   #Will have your network interface be managed the old way. It means fully configured by the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ethX files.
   NM_CONTROLLED="no"
   ```

Comment: check both machine's default route, try `ip route` on both machines.

Comment: Here is my default route. It is the same before and after my issue happen: 
`default via 172.30.0.97 dev eth2`  
`169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1 scope link metric 1004`  
`172.30.0.96/29 dev eth2 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.0.99`

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever find the cause?

Comment: No, I still not found the root cause of this issue.